# Java instance variable type for nosql column

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

What do you declare an instance variable that will be filled by a factory class that retrieves its data from a NOSQL DB?

Right now the column has 1, 0, true, and false in it.  When I declare a class with an instance variable of Boolean I get an exception when the row contains a 1 as you can not put an int into a Boolean.

Comment: Does your NoSQL DB have typing? How is the data stored? Unfortunately, it seems like you're looking for the kind of functionality that C provides with integers. Maybe read the values in as a String and then check?

Comment: Its an AWS Dynamo DB.  Using the AWS APIGateWay I have to give it a class for the factory method.  The JSON return field is either 1, 0, true or false and its taking an exception when the value is 1 and its trying to put it into an int.  Thoughts?

Comment: As far as I know, a DynamoDB has types for each attribute, which means that the data for the particular field you're working with has the AttributeType 'S' (String). This means that when you read the data from the table, you'll need to store it in a String variable initially. From there you can do some checking to determine whether the value should be processed as `true` ("1" or "true") or processed as `false` ("0" or "false").